# Network call from Browser Extension Popup

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I'm trying to make a browser extension that takes input from a user in the pop-up bar and then uploads it to S3 using AWS-Amplify `Storage.put()`. Currently the upload process is happening from within the pop-up.

The problem is that if during the upload is in progress, user clicks outside the pop-up - it closes and on re-opening the state is lost and there is no way of tracking the put request. Now I obviously store the state in background but the issue is I cannot use AWS amplify APIs from the background script. On researching I was able to find the following alternatives -

1. Injecting a content script in a tab and then uploading from there.

My problem with this approach is that what if the user terminates the tab which is uploading? Overall this approach seems very hacky.

2. Opening a new tab/window for upload and asking the user explicitly to not close it before upload succeeds.

Can anyone please suggest a better approach? I'm new to browser extensions and have been following the documentation for firefox extensions (MDN).

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you upload in the background script? If it's because you're using ManifestV3 and the library uses DOM/XMLHttpRequest, then you should be able to make the request explicitly via the built-in `fetch` without this library.

Comment: I read on the web that you can't use external libraries in background, the only suggested alternative was injecting a content script and using the library there. Is it possible to do something like this in background? I'm using manifest v2 for now.

Comment: Don't use an external library then, put the js file of the library inside the extension just like any other script you write. Or just don't use this library and make a `fetch`  as I suggested.